# How to change value of element

Tags: javascript, html

Im kinda new to js, trying to change value of "email" input field

```
<div class="input-group type-email">
    <div class="input-label  has-placeholder-label">
        <label for="">Your Email Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input name="email" value="" placeholder="" type="email">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've found a bunch of articles saying how to find an element by id. How can I do it without id, by type maybe?
Thank you.

Comment: That label's `for` attr is bad. You can fix it by giving the input an ID (`id="email"`, say) and updating the for attr to refer to the ID (`for="email"`). http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('email')[0]`, or if the control is in a form there are more convenient methods, both will work in every browser everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query selectors, for example:

```
var input = document.querySelector("input[name=email]");
input.value = "Your new value";
```

More on query selectors [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and also [**here**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css_selectors_api.shtml).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also consider [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName).